# How to check Image.Source doesn't contains URI or Stream?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have List of 3 Images of type Xamarin.Forms.Image. First image has URI as source, Second image has stream that as I have uploaded second image from Gallery and I don't have anything in 3rd image.

```
List<Image> Photos = new List<Image>();
Image URIImage=ImageSource.FromURI("https://xxx.amazonaws.com/profiles/ddddd-1658-4cf1-b62c-cccccccc_1.jpg");
Photos.Add(URIImage); 
Photos.Add(await GetImageFromGallery());    //"/Users/text/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3C26B8DD-1E37-47A0-B164-810AE3EA4A4D/data/Containers/Data/Application/05BE5988-4F9F-4E17-BCC2-xxxxxxxx/Documents/IMG_0001.JPG"
Photos.Add(new Image() { Source = string.Empty });
```

Now I want to go through loop and want to get image from `Photos` that doesn't have source. Here it's 3rd image of `Photos` list.

Can anybody please help me?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: @SeM I have tried by check Image.Source null condition. I have also noticed that there is `{file=""}` in Image.Source for the images that doesn't have image. But I don't know how can I check `{file = ""}` in Image.Source as I am not able to get any property like `file`. Please suggest.

Comment: I debug your code on my side , the `Source` is null.

Comment: @ColeXia-MSFT I am sorry. I just edit my code. You can check now. I can't put all code here. I have just given example. Actually I have list of 8 images `List<Image>` which all 8 are initialized with `new Image() { Source = string.Empty }`. On app starts, it get few images from web api call. User have option to add remaining images from Gallery. User can add any remove any images. Now the point is user have option to select multiple images from gallery. So, let's say user has selected 3 images, I need to go through loop to find which element doesn't have `Source`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After read the comment, I think the simple solution is checking the string converted from `image.source`.

You can use the two as condition

`image.Source.ToString() is "File: "`

or

`image.Source.ToString().Contains("File: ")`

Comment: Great! Thanks :)

Comment: image.Source.ToString().Contains("File: ") work fine, first option not work.